# How can I write an object into a txt or csv file with?

Tags: java, object, collections, hashmap

All I get is an address of the hashmap, filewriter doesn't work, I've tried everything: scanner, bufferedwriter, re-writing the write() method.

```
public class hmapTest implements java.io.Serializable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<Integer, String> hmap3 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        // add elements to hashmap

        hmap3.put(1, "to");
        hmap3.put(2, "in");
        hmap3.put(3, "at");
        hmap3.put(4, "on");
        hmap3.put(5, "under");

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("hashser.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream ous = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            ous.writeObject(hmap3);
            ous.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

> ¬í¬íloadFactorI etc

Comment: Should it be a human readable form, or just serialized for later deseralization?

Comment: human readable in a txt (csv, whatever), like this: `1 to 2 in` and so on. Of course, the next step is to read it from a txt or a csv into a hasmap list to be displayed in console

Comment: `HashMap` to text is not difficult, but `Properties` provides read+write out of the box: for .properties and XML both.

Comment: Serialized streams are not text. Therefore they should,not be saved in files with the `.txt` extension.

Comment: Thank you all, I understood how it works, the pointers in the txt file just store the hashmap data, it can only be displayed in the console through some more code using ObjectInputStream, if th qs is considered redundant it should be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need an arbitary human readable form you could do something like this:

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<>();
        hmap.put(1, "to");
        hmap.put(2, "in");
        hmap.put(3, "at");
        hmap.put(4, "on");
        hmap.put(5, "under");

        try (XMLEncoder stream = new XMLEncoder(new BufferedOutputStream(System.out))) {
            stream.writeObject(hmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Yet, if it has to be CSV, you have to use a third party library (e.g. https://poi.apache.org/) , or implement it on your own. Also, if your data, is just a list of continues integers mapping to values, consider using a `List`  instead of a `HashMap`.

Comment: Thank you, as I am a beginner I don't understand properly the way these tools work, eg I definitely I'm not able to implement any of your suggestions on my own (unless I spend the rest of my life trying), nevertheless, your code displays something in the console, but not in the csv file. In real life I imagine I'll have to work with databases and write/read the keys and values previously stored in a hashmap in another table(a csv, or a txt). Thank you for your time and input, again.